# Regular Expression for rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to integrate an open source forum in to my WordPress installation, I can figure out the next steps if I can just get a rewrite rule to work, I have the following so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forum/qa\-theme/(.*) forum-embed/qa-theme/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/qa\-content/(.*) forum-embed/qa-content/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/([\w]+)$ forum/?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The first two rules work, but the last one, I've tried all sorts of changes to this regular expression - I want to take *whatever* comes after `forum/` and to put it in to a query string as the `url` parameter.  I'm sure I'm tip-toeing around the expression - what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

> It's also not clear how you are avoiding conflicts with the WordPress front-controller? Presumably you are placing these directives at the top of the .htaccess file, before the # BEGIN WordPress section? However, it may be simpler to create another .htaccess file inside the /forum subdirectory instead and this will (by default) override the WordPress directives.

A sound point, yes I was putting it above the # BEGIN WordPress, but I will make a .htaccess in the forum directory.

> You say you've "tried all sorts of changes to this regular expression", but this regex certainly won't match your first example. The \w shorthand character class excludes slashes and hyphens.

True, this was a bad example to show where I was up to on my question, but I've also tried:

- ^forum/(.+)$
- ^forum/([a-z-A-Z-0-9-/]+)$

> /forum/ is presumably a filesystem directory - this itself can't handle the request, it requires further rewriting to an actual file

I don't understand -- the first two rules work, and I can navigate to all pages, including `forum/` -- index.php is the default file in the config, why must this rule be an exception?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention links example like FROM which link TO which link you want to rewrite? That will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Of course.
Example 1: forum/2/test-question => forum/?url=2/test-question
Example 2: forum/ask => forum/?url=ask

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, still few questions are there. 1st- how we will know(by condition) in which rule 2 arguments should be send as query string(your 1st URL example) and where to send only 1 parameter(as query string)? Also `forum/ask => forum/?url=ask` is NOT having file name by which it will get served in backend, like index.php etc? Kindly confirm on these once and I could try to help you.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you 100% there, but I really only need to take the entire group ($1) as the only parameter to the query string (url) - I can break down the value on the receiving page as required.  Does that help?

Comment: Sorry its not clear to me still. There are 2 questions from my side. 1st- Where you are collecting query string to which file you are sending in backend eg:(index.php OR index.html etc)? 2nd- you said you want everything of $1 to send as query string but from where to decide what value is $1 having? Like in URL `forum/2/test-question` its sending 2 values to query string BUT in URL `forum/ask` its sending 1 value to query string. Kindly do let me know on these points once, thank you.

Comment: Sorry - I think I see your confusion now - didn't format my comment.  Both examples are sending one value.  To summarize again, everything that trails "forum/" gets sent as one parameter.  Example 1: `forum/2/test-question` => `forum/?url=2/test-question`, example 2: `forum/ask` => `forum/?url=ask`.  Also, there is no need to direct the target url to an index(.php/.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^forum/([\w]+)$ forum/?url=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> Example 1: forum/2/test-question => forum/?url=2/test-question

You say you've "tried all sorts of changes to this regular expression", but this regex certainly won't match your first example. The `\w` shorthand character class excludes slashes and hyphens. If you want to match "*whatever* comes after `forum/`", then you could just use `(.+)` (*like* your previous examples, except `+` instead of `*` to avoid a rewrite loop, ie. to avoid matching `/forum/`). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(.+) forum/?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, `forum/?url=whatever` is still not a valid end-point (as @RavinderSingh13 has pointed out in comments). `/forum/` is presumably a filesystem directory - this itself can't handle the request, it requires further rewriting to an actual file (perhaps you are expecting mod_dir to issue a subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex`?). For example, should it be `/forum/index.php?url=whatever`?

It's also not clear how you are avoiding conflicts with the WordPress front-controller? Presumably you are placing these directives at the top of the `.htaccess` file, before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section? However, it may be simpler to create another `.htaccess` file inside the `/forum` subdirectory instead and this will (by default) override the WordPress directives.

You should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper since it's not required here.

---

**UPDATE:**

> > /forum/ is presumably a filesystem directory - this itself can't handle the request, it requires further rewriting to an actual file
>
> I don't understand -- the first two rules work, and I can navigate to all pages, including forum/ -- index.php is the default file in the config, why must this rule be an exception?

We don't know what requests the first two rules are expected to handle, but I *assume* they are just rewriting *static files*?

When you request the *directory* `/forum/` then mod_dir must later issue a subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex` document. When you rewrite the request to `/forum` then mod_dir must still perform this additional processing later. In the meantime rewrite processing loops in `.htaccess` and `/forum/` is passed back through the rewrite engine. This may or may not work - it can result in other conflicts - at the very least it is additional/unnecessary processing. You should rewrite directly to the file that handles the request to cut out this additional processing. In the same way the WordPress code block rewrites the request to `/index.php`, not `/`.

To clarify, when you request `/forum/` only then the above directive is not triggered and mod_dir issues a subrequest for `/forum/index.php`. There is no `url` parameter.

#### Updated directives

However, if rewriting to `/forum/index.php`, you'll need additional checks to avoid `/forum/index.php` being caught by the same rule and resulting in a rewrite loop (500 error).

For example, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^forum/(.+) forum/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The *condition* that checks against `REQUEST_FILENAME` may be optional, depending on whether there are any static resources served from this directory tree?

Alternatively, if your URLs do not contain dots then you may get away with a more restrictive regex instead to avoid matching URLs containing dots. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([^.]+)$ forum/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

#### `/forum/.htaccess`

If moving these directives to the `/forum/.htaccess` file you would rewrite them as follows (and remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^qa-theme/(.*) /forum-embed/qa-theme/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^qa-content/(.*) /forum-embed/qa-content/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `QSA` flag is not required on the first two directives since the query string is passed through by default. (Although if these are rewriting static resources then you wouldn't expect a query string to be passed anyway?)

No need to backslash-escape the hyphen in the regex, since it carries no special meaning when used outside of a character class. Likewise, the dot carries no special meaning when used *inside* a character class so does not need to be backslash-escaped in the last rule above.

Comment: @Jester I've updated my answer with some revised directives and rewrote a version that could be used in the `/forum/.htaccess` file if you decide to move the directives there.

Comment: *VERY* informative - thank you.  Marking as accepted answer.  I spoke to soon before, there is no `forum` directory, only `forum-embed` where it is installed to.  Forum is just a page within Wordpress and you were both right that it turns out I need to redirect to a static file.  Since I cannot do this in the current implementation, I'll attack it in another way.  Many thanks for all of the advice!